# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 AND Robotium test cases hang until back/home pressed on emulator, WHY?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I am developing a graphing calculator app with a single activity. (Android API 10)
The layout is rather complicated with 40+ buttons taking up the bottom half of the screen
and a a frame layout as the top part of the screen. The frame layout is a subclassed into a
"ScreenFrame" which holds the "screen" of the calculator. EVERY view/viewgroup that
gets displayed in the ScreenFrame is a custom view/viewgroup which displays the calculations
the user is performing. Think TI graphing calculator, where the entire expression can be seen
with operation symbols...

I have been writing JUnit tests, mostly subclassing AndroidTestCase because I only need
a context to test a huge portion of the code, not the entire activity framework.
However I am getting to the point where I would like to begin writing functional test cases
and certain parts of the app require the entire activity frame work to operate.

So here is the problem which has me utterly stumped.
First I will show the code for the test case

```
public class CommandTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Calculator> {

    private Calculator _calculator;

    public CommandTest(){
        super(Calculator.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
        _calculator = getActivity();
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        _calculator.finish(); // doesn't make a difference if this line is there or not
    }

    public void testCircleBadSyntax1() {
        _calculator.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                Button twoButton = (Button) _calculator.findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
                twoButton.performClick();
                Button addButton = (Button) _calculator.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
                addButton.performClick();
                Button nineButton = (Button) _calculator.findViewById(R.id.nineButton);
                nineButton.performClick();
                Button enterButton = (Button) _calculator.findViewById(R.id.equalsButton);
                enterButton.performClick();
             }
        });
        Instrumentation inst = getInstrumentation();
        inst.waitForIdleSync();

        _calculator.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override public void run() {
                 ScreenFrame screenFrame = (ScreenFrame) _calculator.findViewById(R.id.screenFrame);
                 assertNotNull(screenFrame);
                 AnswerSymbolGroup answer = screenFrame.getLastAnswer();
                 INumber number = answer.getNumberAnswer();
                 assertEquals(number.getValueInt(), 11); 
            }
    });
        _calculator.finish();
    }
}
```

I just showed you how I was setting everything up and a single example test case above. All tests cases are similar, and what is getting tested is not the problem... The main problem is that when I run the test through eclipse, the test just hangs on the first test case instance indefinitely, (I tried leaving it for a while just to see and it just sat there with a blue arrow on the first case for 45+ minutes). The extremely strange part is that when I press either the HOME button, or the back button on the emulator, the test case runs. And it gives the appropriate response. You don't see any of the screen changes or other things that you should see when buttons are pressed, but the test case runs as it should. meaning it passes, or fails depending on the code I am testing. Then the test runner hangs on the next test until I press the back or home button again.

This isn't a workable solution. I would like to have ten to twenty cases (sometimes a lot more) in a Test file and I would like to have them all run in successful without having to press anything on the emulator, especially since I have a Jenkins CI set up which I use for all the other tests I have without a problem.

So I thought that a framework like robotium for these types of tests would be better suited to handle these types of tests.

I am having the same problem with robotium. When I run a robotium test case with the home screen on the emulator showing, the test case starts, brings up the calculator screen, then hangs indefinitely. When I press the back button, then reopen the app, the test case starts from the beginning and proceeds to work as it should, meaning it passes if the code it is testing is correct, while fails if not. You do, however, get to see the appropriate changes with the robotium cases. For instance, if the given test were adjusted to use a solo variable to click the buttons and none of the runOnUiThreads stuff, a two would appear on the screen after the two button is pressed, then the plus, the nine, and eleven after enter is pressed. On the next test case, same thing happens, it hangs indeinifitely. When I click back, or home, then reopen the app the test will proceed. Each test case I have to repeat this process. I haven't tried running these tests in my jenkins unit, (still working out how to run a robotium test headless).

I have been stumped on this for quite a few days and don't feel like I should waste any more time trying to figure it out. Has anyone else experienced this type of behavior.

I typically detest using the debugger to find errors cause I find it is far more time consuming then writing tests and logging the appropriate output to LOGCAT. I have however tried running the debugger on this situation to find out where things are hanging.
I know that the test case hangs on the getActivity() line... I get to the point in the debugger where i am looping in the main looper. The onCreate(), onStart(), and onResume()
methods are are completed, and the the entire screen is visible, but once that happens
it hangs until i  hit the back button or home button.

I would really like to figure out why this happens and be able to have multiple test cases run in succession.

/** Added After the first TWO answers came **/
To the first answer, I already had tried putting the activity.finish() in the tearDown() method, it makes no difference...

To the second answer, I have tried every possible enumeration of where to place the super.setUp() and super.tearDown() within the tests setUp and tearDown(), with not including them as one of the options.

I tried running through the debugger getActivity() method more thoroughly and can say that the code gets stuck in the Instrumentation class in the startActivitySync(Intent intent) method.

on line 391 getTargetContext().startActivity(intent) is ran, and then it sits on the next portion on the sync lock ...

```
getTargetContext().startActivity(intent);

do{
    try{
        mSync.wait();
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
}while(mWaitingActivities.contains(aw));

return aw.activity;
```

Comment: Is it possible that an infinitely repeating animation on a view could cause the hang and not ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. did you get solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your tearDown method, you need to call _calculator.finish();

For tests that open multiple activities, robotium has a convenience method to finish all of them: solo.finishOpenedActivities();

Comment: I didn't show that in the code that I posted, but I do call those methods in the tearDown() method, and there is only a single activity in my app....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help you, however you should call `super.setUp();` at the beginning of setUp method and `super.tearDown();` at the end of tearDown method. You can also try to remove them.

By the way calling `setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);` doesn't make sense, because:

> If you do not call this, the touch mode will be false. If you call
>   this after your Activity has been started, it will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I could solve my problem by putting the `setAdapter()` method in the `AsyncTask` class.